# loading page using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, struts2

I want to load part of the page using JQuery ajax.

url is Struts2 action request.

```
$("#accountListDiv").html(ajax_load).load(url, $("#testform").serializeArray(),   function(){
    //alert('done');
});
```

//serializeArray and serialize is not working. (May be struts action do expect data in the format in which it is generated by these functions. More insights on this issue will be helpful).

In case of normal HTTP request, all variable in Struts2 action will be automatically assigned values as entered in JSP page.

I want to do the same while using Ajax. I don't want to pass each and every parameter in form explicitly like this.

```
$("#indexDiv").html(ajax_load).load(url, "rateTypeId4Index="+rateTypeId4Index, function(){
    xyz();
});
```

I know there is Dojo plugin for struts, but it is deprecated. And if I am able to solve this issue using JQuery then its more than sufficient for me.

(I am looking for solution which does not involve use of JQuery-struts plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Your have a problem in sending request, not in Struts2 part. Try to set a map of parameters instead of string.

```
$("#accountListDiv").html(ajax_load).load(url, {'param1':value1, 'param2':value2},   function(){
    //alert('done');
});
```

2 If your want to submit a form using ajax, use [Jquery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#download) plugin.

```
  $("#testform").ajaxSubmit({
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#accountListDiv').html(data);
        alert('Yeh-ha!');        
      },
      error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Oops');
      }}
  );
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is valid, But i don't want to do it as there are large number of parameters in page. Second one is refreshing the page (Also it is not updating the testform div). May be I am not able to correctly embed it. Anyway I will keep trying and keep you updated.

Comment: looks like your first solution is the only way to pass multiple parameters to struts application using JQuery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean to use `serialize` rather than `serializeArray`

Comment: I tried using it but it did not work. That's why, I also want to know how struts2 parse the input data and set value of each variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following with JQuery and Struts2:

```
<script>

    function bindDivFormSubmission(theDiv) {

        /* get the form from the div and unbind it */
        var theForm = theDiv.find('form');
        theForm.unbind();

         /* attach a submit handler to the form */
        theForm.submit(function(event) {

            /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var url = theForm.attr( 'action' ),
                formData = theForm.serialize();

            /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
            $.post( url, formData,
              function( data ) {
                  theDiv.html( data );
                  bindDivFormSubmission(theDiv);
              }
            );

        });

    }

    var accountListDiv = $("#accountListDiv");

    bindDivFormSubmission(accountListDiv);

</script>
```

You may notice that it recursively calls "bindDivFormSubmission(theDiv);" after replacing the div.  This was because in my use the div is replaced with another form that needs to be bound.